# How can I run two tasks concurrently using invoke?

Tags: python, concurrency

I am trying to create a tool chain for a project by using [Invoke](https://www.pyinvoke.org/). One of the tools will be used to run the solution which has two parts, a frontend and a backend, these parts have to run concurrently.

I am struggling with the concurrency.

Here is what my code looks like right now:

```
from invoke import task

#################################################################
# running the app
#################################################################
    
@task
def run_frontend(context):
    with context.cd("services/frontend/"):
        context.run("nvm use 18")
        context.run("npm start")
          
            
@task
def run_backend(context):
    with context.cd("services/backend/"):
        context.run("poetry shell")
        context.run("python main.py")


@task
def run(context):
    run_backend(context)
    run_frontend(context)
```

When run this runs the backend and then waits for it to be closed before continuing. I have tried using `runners` and `Collection` without success